# Parsing Ansible output with Linux tools

Tags: ansible

I have a silly playbook which just runs a command to get the list of vhost in every host on webserver group. As all vhost are located in /var/www is easy to get the list of webs.

The problem is the way of Ansible returns the info. For example:

```
ok: [host1] => {
    "var": {
        "out.stdout_lines": [
            "",
            "host1.com"
        ]
    }
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "var": {
        "out.stdout_lines": [
            "",
            "host2.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

Do you know an easy way to just get the name of the vhosts? Using grep awk or something like that?

Answer (score 8):

Dirty way: prepend each line in `stdout_lines` with some marker (e.g. `ANSBLMRK_`) before printing, so you have a list if "ANSBLMRK_host2.com", then `grep` and `cut`.

Good way: set `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json` and pipe it to `jq`.

Comment: hi Konstantin, this ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK is some sort of plugin?

Comment: yes, you can customize ansible output with plugins. `json` is a standard one that prints all playbook output to a JSON object, so you can easily parse it with other tools like `jq`, for example.

Comment: `stdout_callback = json`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just write a file containing the hosts names in your playbook and then use that later:

```
tasks:

- name: make output file
  file: name=./list_of_hosts state=touch

- name: show my hostname
  lineinfile: dest=./list_of_hosts line="{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    "{{ out.stdout_lines[1] }}"
```